# Exit or end another executable

Tags: c#

I have this code to run the exe:

```
String cPath = "C:\\GCOS\\HHT\\EXE\\" + frmSchemas.schema;
string cParams = HHTNUMBER+" "+ Login.user + "/" + Login.pass + "//" +Login.db + "//" + frmSchemas.schema ;
string filename = Path.Combine(cPath,"HHTCtrlp.exe"); 
Process.Start(filename, cParams);
```

Now how do i end the program above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("HHTCtrlp");
        foreach (var process in processes)
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample from http://csharp-slackers.blogspot.com/2008/09/terminate-process.html

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class TerminateProcessExample {

public static void Main () {

    // Create a new Process and run notepad.exe.
    using (Process process = Process.Start("notepad.exe")) {

        // Wait for 5 seconds and terminate the notepad process.
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting 5 seconds before terminating" +
            " notepad.exe.");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        // Terminate notepad process.
        Console.WriteLine("Terminating Notepad with CloseMainWindow.");

        // Try to send a close message to the main window.
        if (!process.CloseMainWindow()) {

            // Close message did not get sent - Kill Notepad.
            Console.WriteLine("CloseMainWindow returned false - " +
                " terminating Notepad with Kill.");
            process.Kill();

        } else {

            // Close message sent successfully; wait for 2 seconds
            // for termination confirmation before resorting to Kill.
            if (!process.WaitForExit(2000)) {

                Console.WriteLine("CloseMainWindow failed to" +
                    " terminate - terminating Notepad with Kill.");
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
    }

    // Wait to continue.
    Console.WriteLine("Main method complete. Press Enter.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

As you can see, there are more graceful ways to try to terminate a process than just using `Process.Kill();`

Answer (score 1):

Keep a handle to the process - [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) returns a [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) object.

You can then use (in extremis):

```
process.Kill();
```

to stop it.

Using:

```
process.CloseMainWindow();
```

is probably a better way (assuming the process has a UI)

Answer (score 1):

**Process.Start** will return a **Process** instance. You can call [Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) on the instance to terminate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your process to a variable and call the Kill method. i.e.

```
String cPath = "C:\\GCOS\\HHT\\EXE\\" + frmSchemas.schema;
string cParams = HHTNUMBER+" "+ Login.user + "/" + Login.pass + "//" +Login.db + "//" + frmSchemas.schema ;
string filename = Path.Combine(cPath,"HHTCtrlp.exe"); 
var p = Process.Start(filename, cParams); 
// ... Later in Code ...
p.Kill();
```

Comment: As documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx

Comment: Kill is not being recognised :( am i missing something?

Comment: Kill is part of the process object. You need to make sure you assign the process to a variable and aren't trying to call it like a static method (i.e. p.Kill() not Process.Kill())

Answer (score 0):

You can keep hold of the process you start:

```
var example_process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

And later:

```
example_process.Kill();
```

Comment: String cPath = "C:\\GCOS\\HHT\\EXE\\" + frmSchemas.schema; string cParams = HHTNUMBER+" "+ Login.user + "/" + Login.pass + "//" +Login.db + "//" + frmSchemas.schema ; var p = Path.Combine(cPath,"HHTCtrlp.exe"); p.Kill();

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = Process.Start(filename, cParams);
...
p.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process proc = Process.Start(filename, cParams); 
 // ....
proc.CloseMainWindow();
proc.Close();
// ...or the rude way ;) ...
proc.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the process ID to kill it.

```
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses()) 
{
  if (proc.Id == _processID) 
  {
    proc.Kill();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process q;
q = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
q.Kill();
```