# Open and close internet browser with C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a simple console application in C# that I'm going to use to poll three URLs in order to update a website that was produced by a third party (stock levels, product images etc.). The console application is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"http://URL1");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"http://URL2");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"http://URL3");
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly but leaves the windows open (three tabs on in a single browser instance). As this will run every hour or so, is there a way I can also get the application to 'kill' the windows once they have been opened? Otherwise the system memory will slowly be consumed by Internet Explorer sessions.

I couldn't find anything else regarding closing browsers from a console application but if I'm wrong please point in the right direction.

Nothing else will be using the browsers so it doesn't need to check if the browser was opened by the console, it just needs to close the application. It will be running as a scheduled task on a remote server. Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

The simplest way was to change to `HttpWebRequest` as suggested. Resultant code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpWebRequest myReq1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://URL1");
    HttpWebRequest myReq2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://URL2");
    HttpWebRequest myReq3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://URL3");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024731/exit-or-end-another-executable

Comment: Is it possible to have `Console.Readine()` and then just add `Process.Kill()` after that ?

Comment: If you're not interested in the actual browser instances, and its just for making a request to a url, consider just making an Http request using `HttpWebRequest` or a `WebClient`

Comment: @Jamiec That sounds like a much better idea - I'll look into that! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a browser instance to request a URL, your console app should request the URL using either a [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or an [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you - I did not know you could do this, and this negates the need for me to close the browsers (or open them in the first place).

Answer (score -1):

You can kill the browser process by name:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore.exe"))
{
  process.Kill();
}
```

Comment: and then the users want to know where all their open windows have gone!

Comment: @richard What windows? There are no users using browsers according to the OP: "Nothing else will be using the browsers so it doesn't need to check if the browser was opened by the console, it just needs to close the application."

Comment: @Richard A good point but this will be running as a scheduled task on a remote server and the browser is not used for anything else - I've updated the question to clarify further. Thanks!

Comment: @itsme86 Thank you for the answer - I voted it up but using `HttpWebRequest` suits my needs better (as I don't really NEED the browser instances in the first place) as pointed out by Jamiec.

Comment: @Lyall There is an awareness in my comment that others looking to solve this may not pick up that caveat in your case (and also note, a console application can open a dialog with an embedded browser: useful where you want to control it but user interactivity is needed).

Comment: @Richard good point :)